# RSpec convert from old to new syntax

Tags: rspec, rspec2

I want to convert from old RSpec Syntax:

```
describe "User pages" do
  subject { page }
  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }
    it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign up') }
  end
end
```

to the new Syntax:

```
RSpec.describe "UserPages", :type => :request do
  subject { page }
  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { expect(subject).to have_selector("h1") }
    it { expect(subject).to have_content("Sign up") }

  end
end
```

How can i convert the 2 expect lines to a single one? Something like: expect(subject).to have_selector("h1") and_to have_content("Sign up")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
it { expect(subject).to have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign up') }
```

Other than using single quotes, exactly the same general syntax that you expressed. :)

Or, if you like the specificity of a full xpath path:

```
it { expect(subject).to have_selector(:xpath, '//div/h1', text: 'Sign up') }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following options:

1. use xpath matcher like this:

   ```
   it { expect(subject).to have_xpath("//h1[contains(., 'Sign up')]") }
   ```
2. write your own custom matcher:
   https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-4/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher
   where you can use existing matchers like have_selector and have_content
3. compose your matchers:
   https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-1/docs/composing-matchers